# Keep browser cache updated using fingerprinting or Etag

Tags: php, rest, caching

I am implementing a cache for a RESTApi service setting the headers. 
Now the problem is, how to force the browser to get data from the server and not from cache in case of updating data? I was thinking about `finger printing` but how can I apply it to url's like this:

```
data?city=rome&age=22
```

where foreach different value of parameters I can have differents responses.

Comment: HTTP caching works based on URLs. If you have different parameters, it is a different URL. Naturally you would have to “finger print” the data set this specific URL returns, for each URL.

Comment: @CBroe that also what I thought. But how to check if the data has changed?

Comment: Do you mean how to determine on the server side that the data has changed, or how to get the client to check if it has? (If it is the latter, then I consider this question way too broad, and would ask you to go read up on the basics of how that works first of all please.)

Comment: Yes, how the client knows that content has changed? If in browser cache I have for example data?city=rome&age=22.somehash123 how the browser knows that content has changed?

Comment: By asking the server again. And then the server either responds with “no, nothing has changed, you’re good to use the data you already got again”, or with the new, changed data.

Comment: Now the question is, if to get fresh data from server I need 1.8 seconds, will I really save time just sending a request to server to decide if data are updated or not?

Comment: Caching is not only about “saving time”, there’s other limited resources involved as well here. (Like for example a mobile data plan’s limited traffic volume.)

Comment: I totally agree with that

Answer (score -1):

Try these headers:

```html
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
```